# How I can change a Heroku stack for GitHub app?

Tags: github, heroku

Hi and thanks for reading me
I am trying to upload an application to Heroku but I want to do it on Heroku-18, is there any way to change the stack?

It's an app that I have on Github, so I'm a bit lost in how I changed :(

Thanks for the help

[image: Stack pic]

Answer (score 0):

Heroku-20 is the default stack for new apps, but you can still change it back to Heroku-18 using

```
heroku stack:set heroku-18 -a <<app_name>>
```